# calc() not working in Firefox

Tags: css, calc

I am trying to use calc() to get my page contents to fit on the page perfectly. I have a header with a height of 52px. I am trying to make a container 100% of the page -50px to it fits onto the page perfectly, however as it does work in Chrome, Edge, and Internet Explorer, it doesn't in Firefox.

Chrome:
[Chrome result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8IkD.png)

Firefox:
[Firefox result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF41b.png)

```css
div#container {

 width: 20%;

 height: 100%;

 height: calc(100% - 52px);

 height: -moz-calc(100% - 52px);

 height: -webkit-calc(100% - 52px);

 float: left;

}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I am trying using your CSS but getting a comment in VS 2017 in this line height: -moz-calc(100% - 52px); that it's not a valid value for the Height property. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out I need to set the height of the body to 100% for it to take effect. Just thought I would let other users know in case they come across the same problem.

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: For me html and body didn't work, I had to add it to the closest parent component that was 100% height