# Cannot make work Calc() css property in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper with a class that sets it's height based on a calc() wich is working smoothly on all browsers except in firefox. This is the snippet

```
  width: 340px;

  float: left;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  scrollbar-width: thin;

  height: calc(100% - 120px);
```

Any idea of what's happening or what I'm missing out?

Comment: Does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029822/calc-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

try with `vh`

```
height: calc(100vh - 120px);
```

Comment: Totally fixed the problem. But what's the reason why 100% isn't working? I'm using percentages also on more parts of my CSS and everything works

Comment: parent height problem